# How can I get Sidekiq to work with Mailboxer message emails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-4.1, mailboxer

I'm on Rails 4.1 trying to work with the [Mailboxer Gem](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer) and Sidekiq, and I followed along with the documentation and the sample app in the docs to set everything up. Then I configured the mailers to use UserMailer with this in the `initializers/mailboxer.rb`:

```
config.notification_mailer = UserMailer
config.message_mailer = UserMailer
```

Everything works pretty much as expected, both on the site and receiving emails when messages are sent or replied to. Next, I tried to have the mail jobs done asynchronous using Sidekiq using this code I got from [one of the issues on the Mailboxer github page](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer/issues/189). This also is in the initializer:

```
config.custom_deliver_proc = ->(mailer, mailable, recipient) do
  mailer.delay.send_email(mailable, recipient)
end
```

However, now when I send a message, it hits Sidekiq but it throws this error:

```
ArgumentError: undefined class/module Mailboxer::Message
```

Here's the relevant code in user_mailer.rb:

```
def send_email(message, receiver)
  if message.conversation.messages.size > 1
    reply_message_email(message,receiver)
  else
    new_message_email(message,receiver)
  end
end

#Sends an email for indicating a new message for the receiver
def new_message_email(message,receiver)
  @message  = message
  @receiver = receiver
  set_subject(message)
  mail :to => receiver.send(Mailboxer.email_method, message),
     :subject => t('mailboxer.message_mailer.subject_new', :subject => @subject),
     :template_name => 'new_message_email'
end

#Sends and email for indicating a reply in an already created conversation
def reply_message_email(message,receiver)
  @message  = message
  @receiver = receiver
  set_subject(message)
  mail :to => receiver.send(Mailboxer.email_method, message),
     :subject => t('mailboxer.message_mailer.subject_reply', :subject => @subject),
     :template_name => 'reply_message_email'
end
```

I'm not currently using notifications so I haven't included that. Where is it calling Mailboxer::Message, and what arguments does it expect? Is this a Rails 4.1 thing? I'm still pretty new to Ruby/Rails, sorry if this is an obvious error on my part.

I also tried calling `delay` on the individual methods in UserMailer, with the same result:

```
def send_email(message, receiver)
  if message.conversation.messages.size > 1
    UserMailer.delay.reply_message_email(message,receiver)
  else
    UserMailer.delay.new_message_email(message,receiver)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE: The syntax changed in Rails 4.2 and above. See [Tomasz's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31657255/3477163) for new syntax.**

---

We upgraded to Rails 4.1.4 and I tried the same code again and it worked this time. I put

```
config.custom_deliver_proc = ->(mailer, mailable, recipient) do
  mailer.delay.send_email(mailable, recipient)
end
```

at the *end* of the initializer, not sure if the placement makes a difference.

I'm still not exactly sure why the same code works now and didn't before, but my theory is that this was a Rails 4.1.0 issue that was fixed with the 4.1.4 upgrade. Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 4):

It didn't work out for me. There is no `delay` method for `mailer`. Take a look here:

```
>> RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.2.0"
>> Rails::VERSION::STRING
=> "4.2.1"

>> mailer.methods.include?(:delay)
=> false
>> mailer.send_email(mailable, recipient).methods.include?(:deliver_later)
=> true
```

So, if you use Rails > 4.2 use this:

```
config.custom_deliver_proc = ->(mailer, mailable, recipient) do
  mailer.send_email(mailable, recipient).deliver_later
end
```

Comment: Confirmed this is the way to do it in rails 5 too, perhaps this should be the accepted answer?

Comment: This is definitely correct for >= 4.2, but my question was specific to 4.1.x